# Getting gradient background color to due full cycle on the outside of a wrapper

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have a page on my site that has a gray background color that I am trying to add gradient to it in a different way than just a left to right. My page has an outer div that takes up 100% of the page's width. I then have an inner div that takes up 80% of the page's with, but auto aligned. I was wondering how, if I can, do a full cycle of my gradient within each side (left & right) of the outer div, the 10% part that shows before the inner div starts.

So say an A equals 10%, and everytime I put two colors together, that is the gradient taking place within that 10%. I want to do this...

#181818, #282828 AAAAAAAA #282828, #181818

How can I do this?

HTML

```
<div class="graypage">
        <div class="homeimg">
             gfdsgsg
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.graypage, .whitepage { margin: 0 auto; }
/*------Page Wraps--------*/
.graypage {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #282828, #181818); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #282828, #181818); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #282828, #181818); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #282828, #181818); /* Standard syntax */
}
.homeimg {
background-image: url("/images/bright_lights_small.jpg");
width: 80%;
 background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you'd like two bars - one on the left of the outerDiv and the other on the right. Each of these bars you'd like to be 10% of the page width. You'd also like each bar to cycle through the colours `#181818, #282828, #aaaaaa, #282828, #181818`.

I'd just use a linear-gradient with 12 colour-stops. Something like this:

```
#outerDiv
{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, 
                                #181818 0%,#282828 2%,#aaaaaa 4%,#aaaaaa 6%,#282828 8%,#181818 10%,
                                #181818 90%,#282828 92%,#aaaaaa 94%,#aaaaaa 96%,#282828 98%,#181818 100%); /* W3C */
    width: 100%;
}
```

Credit: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Here it's applied to the outer div and a solid colour is applied to the (80% as wide) inner div.
[image]

EDIT: Here's the (now updated) html and css used.

```
<style>
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#outerDiv
{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, 
                                #181818 0%,#282828 10%,
                                #282828 90%,#181818 100%); /* W3C */
    width: 100%;
}
#innerDiv
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='outerDiv'>
    <div id='innerDiv'>
        <button id='goBtn'>Change the text</button>
        <div class="menu-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li>WORD1</li>
                <li>WORD2</li>
                <li>WORD3</li>
                <li>WORD4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This code produces the following result:
[image]

Comment: You almost have the right understanding. I am wanting `#282828, #181818` on the left 10% and ` #181818, #282828` on the right

Comment: Okay, easy. Just throw away 8 of the stops. Just use the ones at 0%, 10%, 90% and 100% and set the colour as needed.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong? `.indexgraypage {
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,
  #181818 0%, #282828 10%, #282828 90%, 181818 100%);
}` Nothing is showing up at all.

Answer (score 1):

Bacically, you have 2 posibilities here. You can set a repeating gradient

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, yellow 0%, green 10%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

And you can play with the background-size

```css
    div {
      width: 500px;
      height: 100px;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green);
      background-size: 10% 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```